# Github history on line item

Tags: git, github

I'm looking to see who committed a particular change to a file on a particular line number. For example:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? The current way I am doing this is looking at every single code push to this file, and there are quite a lot to review.

Comment: You can do this in github if click the three dots, as in your screenshot, and select View git blame. Alternatively, tools are available in your favorites IDEs. I use vscode gitlens [https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlen] It helps you to visualize code authorship at a glance via Git blame annotations and code lens,

Comment: @LukeHutton nice! That is super handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, look up `git blame`.

```
git-blame - Show what revision and author last modified each line of a file
```

See also: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

Comment: thanks, that worked: `$ git blame -L149,+3 file.py`.